# Is it possible to execute some code on installed flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

The need is for blocking the spam users from overusing the quota, or prevent DDOS attacks from client applications,
When a `cloud function` sees that the resources are being heavily consumed **(by using admin sdk, collections.onRead property)** by some particular `uid`, it should log the user out from the application by writing `auth.SignOut();` or `exit(0);` in that users firestore record, which is actively being listened by client application, and the client application should then execute that code by referencing to that particular function of `firebase_auth:` library,
Or is there any better approach to achieve this kind of failsafe for these kind of scenarios ?

Answer (score 0):

check `background fetch` so even the app is terminated you can run some functions in the background and keep checking your condition once the condition satisfies call logout.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes

https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Answer (score 0):

The flutter builds an `encrypted` package as an output for your implementation (`codes`).

So it is ***not possible***e to include some more `code`/ execute some codes without rebuilding the package.

But you can use an internet connection to fetch some **config** (`dynamic`) for your application from your custom Backend or **Firebase (remote config)**. By this, you will be able to do some tasks dynamically, such as the theme of the application, the color of a widget, and many more.